# Can we skip a file check while using hadoop fsck command in linux?

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs

I want to skip a file check on a specified path using hadoop fsck command. Can we do it?
I am using the below command:

hadoop fsck  > /output.txt

i have checked the hdfs guide also, but there is nothing to exclude the path from the above command.

kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

As of Hadoop2.9.0, there is no way to specify the exclude paths in hadoop fsck command.

But you can use WebHDFS REST API to get the same File system health information as fsck. Using this API we can get the info for all the files inside a directory using LISTSTATUS api or for a single file using  GETFILESTATUS api.

For Directories:

```
curl -i  "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<DIRECTORY_PATH>?op=LISTSTATUS"
```

For file:

```
curl -i  "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<FILE_PATH>?op=GETFILESTATUS"
```

These will return the response with a FileStatuses JSON object.

Please find below the sample Response returned from NN for Directory:

```
curl -i "http://<NN_HOST>:<HTTP_PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<DIRECTORY_PATH>?op=LISTSTATUS"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.hwx)

{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[
{"accessTime":1489059994224,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":209158298,"group":"hdfs","length":0,"modificationTime":1489059994227,"owner":"XXX","pathSuffix":"_SUCCESS","permission":"644","replication":3,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"FILE"},
{"accessTime":1489059969939,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":209158053,"group":"hdfs","length":0,"modificationTime":1489059986846,"owner":"XXX","pathSuffix":"part-m-00000","permission":"644","replication":3,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"FILE"},
{"accessTime":1489059982614,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":209158225,"group":"hdfs","length":0,"modificationTime":1489059993497,"owner":"XXX","pathSuffix":"part-m-00001","permission":"644","replication":3,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"FILE"},
{"accessTime":1489059977524,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":209158188,"group":"hdfs","length":0,"modificationTime":1489059983034,"owner":"XXX","pathSuffix":"part-m-00002","permission":"644","replication":3,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"FILE"}]}}
```